# DATE with PHP oci_pdo and ORACLE db - TO_DATE doest work

Tags: php, oracle, date

I'm trying to write a date in a Oracle database date column using php and pdo_oci ,but I got the above error and I can't go on:

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1858 OCIStmtExecute: ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected (ext\pdo_oci\oci_statement.c:155)

code:

$invoiceUpdate->PAYMENT_DATE = "TO_DATE('06/MAR/24','dd/mon/yy HH24:MI:SS')";

write date with time into Oracle Database date type column

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the TO_DATE function as provided. But of course, that's not what is executed in Oracle - the entire SQL statement is, and we can't see how this string is embedded in the SQL, so the error could be anywhere. Please provide the full update statement that is being executed.

Comment: @PaulW `There is nothing wrong with the TO_DATE function as provided` ... apart from the string provided doesn't include the time portion but the format model does? Although it wouldn't cause the error the OP mentions

Comment: It wouldn't cause any error, thanks to Oracle's 'helpful' laxness here... better to make them match though, to make it clearer and easier to maintain. But it might error if the NLS data language isn't English and the month abbreviation isn't recognised - still not with that error though. Relying on NLS settings isn't usually a good idea. Also why aren't you binding the value (preferably as  a native date) instead of embedding a string?

Comment: i get the actual date with a var - $date = date('d/M/y H:i:s'), then i use $date var in value to PAYMENT_DATE - "TO_DATE('{$date}','dd/mon/yyyy HH24:MI:SS')"; and the full statement is:

UPDATE TABLE SET PAYMENT_DATE = :PAYMENT_DATE
  
  'PAYMENT_DATE' => string 'TO_DATE('06/Mar/24 16:17:12','dd/mon/yyyy HH24:MI:SS')' (length=54)

Comment: I think your query should include apostrophes surrounding the date value.
`UPDATE TABLE SET PAYMENT_DATE ='06/02/2024 16:17:12' ; `
Maybe build the sql query statement as a string variable and print it before using it.

Answer (score 1):

You said in comments that your actual SQL is:

```
UPDATE TABLE SET PAYMENT_DATE = :PAYMENT_DATE
```

And that the bind variable is defined as:

```
'PAYMENT_DATE' => string 'TO_DATE('06/Mar/24 16:17:12','dd/mon/yyyy HH24:MI:SS')' (length=54)
```

This is binding a *string* rather than a date. It effectively is giving you:

```
UPDATE TABLE SET PAYMENT_DATE = 'TO_DATE(''06/Mar/24 16:17:12'',''dd/mon/yyyy HH24:MI:SS'')'
```

Because it's a string, Oracle will not evaluate the TO_DATE function. It isn't a function, it's just a string of characters 54 bytes long. Because you are setting a date field to this, Oracle will attempt an implicit date conversion using your database (or session's) `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`, which most certainly will not know what to do with letters like `T, O, _, D, A, T, E,` etc.. Hence the error.

To fix, bind an actual date value, not a string. Every client has some way to do that, so consult your language documentation. You *could* get it to work by concatenation into your SQL rather than by bind variable, as then Oracle would evaluate `TO_DATE` as a function, but you'd be making unsharable cursors and spending extra time in unnecessary parsing. It is far better to use bind variables as you're trying to do, but you'll need to bind a *date* (however this looks in your client env) to a date slot, not a string.

Answer (score 0):

> get the actual date with a var - $date = date('d/M/y H:i:s'), then i use $date var in value to PAYMENT_DATE - "TO_DATE('{$date}','dd/mon/yyyy HH24:MI:SS')"; and the full statement is: UPDATE TABLE SET PAYMENT_DATE = :PAYMENT_DATE 'PAYMENT_DATE' => string 'TO_DATE('06/Mar/24 16:17:12','dd/mon/yyyy HH24:MI:SS')' (length=54)

You are binding a string value; the content of that string will not be interpreted as a function call, it will try to use the literal string value. As you are assigning that to a date column it will then implicitly try to convert that to the right data type, so what you actually end up doing is:

```
UPDATE TABLE SET PAYMENT_DATE = to_date(:PAYMENT_DATE)
```

using your NLS settings, FWIW; and if you substitute the string for the bind that would look like;

```
UPDATE TABLE SET PAYMENT_DATE = to_date(q'^TO_DATE('06/Mar/24 16:17:12','dd/mon/yyyy HH24:MI:SS')^')
```

which will indeed throw ORA-01858 because with a normal NLS setting like DD-MON-RR it would be expecting that string to start with two digits, not `TO`. (It might throw a different error depending on the NLS settings...)

You *could* move the `TO_DATE()` call into the fixed query:

```
UPDATE TABLE SET PAYMENT_DATE = TO_DATE(:PAYMENT_DATE, 'DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH')
```

and then bind the string value:

```
$invoiceUpdate->PAYMENT_DATE = "06/MAR/24 16:17:12";
```

You still have a problem, at least with the values you've provided, as you have a 2-digit year but a `YYYY` format model. Using that, `24` will be interpreted as `0024`, not `2024`.

Either make sure the string value also has a 4-digit year:

```
$invoiceUpdate->PAYMENT_DATE = "06/MAR/2024 16:17:12";
```

or use `RRRR` instead of `YYYY`. But using 2-digit years is what led to the Y2K problem so avoid that if you can.

You can see all of that [in this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/KnqhDJNz), which uses a local PL/SQL variable for the string value but the effect is the same.

---

It would be better to bind an actual data value if you can, avoiding that conversion both ways.